# Avoid duplicates when saving new data with mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, ecmascript-6, error-handling

I am working on an application where I can save destinations to my Mongo DB. I would like to throw a custom error when trying to save a destination that already exsist in the DB. Mongoose prevents that from happening but I want clear and userfriendly error handling.

```
// post a new destination

router.post('/',
  (req, res) => {
    const newCity = new cityModel(
      {
        name: req.body.name,
        country: req.body.country
      }
    )
    newCity.save()
      .then(city => {
        res.send(city)
      })
      .catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send('Server error')
      })
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Before saving a new destination, you can check if there is document already using `findOne` method, and if it exists you can return a custom error.

```js
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  const { name, country } = req.body;

  try {
    const existingDestination = await cityModel.findOne({name,country});

    if (existingDestination) {
      return res.status(400).send("Destionation already exists");
    }

    let newCity = new cityModel({ name, country });

    newCity = await newCity.save();
    res.send(city);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send("Server error");
  }
});
```

Note that I guessed the duplication occurs when the same country and name exist. If it is not what you want, you can change the query in findOne.

Comment: I won't argue on this or say shouldn't be done this way, but in general you wouldn't purposefully write duplicates to DB, there could be minimal chances out of many correct ones, but doing this way you need to make two DB calls for all uniques going into DB. The purpose of unique index is not only limited to avoid accidentally creating duplicates but also used to lessen these kind of pre-checks done by app.

Comment: @ZoltanSzokodi why did you changed your mind? This answer is cleaner. And other answer has issues which I commented at that answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've created [unique](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/) index, When you try to write duplicate then the result would be :

```
WriteResult({
   "nInserted" : 0,
   "writeError" : {
      "code" : 11000,
      "errmsg" : "E11000 duplicate key error index: test.collection.$a.b_1 dup key: { : null }"
   }
})
```

**Your code :**

**Constants File :**

```
module.exports = {
    DUPLICATE_DESTINATION_MSG: 'Destionation values already exists',
    DUPLICATE_DESTINATION_CODE: 4000
}
```

**Code :**

```
//post a new destination
const constants = require('path to constants File');
router.post('/',
    (req, res) => {
        const newCity = new cityModel(
            {
                name: req.body.name,
                country: req.body.country
            }
        )
        try {
            let city = await newCity.save();
            res.send(city)
        } catch (error) {
            if (error.code == 11000) res.status(400).send(`Destination - ${req.body.name} with country ${req.body.country} already exists in system`);
            /* In case if your front end reads your error code &
                it has it's own set of custom business relates messages then form a response object with code/message & send it. 
            if (error.code == 11000) {
                let respObj = {
                    code: constants.DUPLICATE_DESTINATION_CODE,
                    message: constants.DUPLICATE_DESTINATION_MSG
                }
                res.status(400).send(respObj);
            } */
        }
        res.status(500).send('Server error');
    })
```

Comment: And what about if there are also other unique indexes, than this code will misguide the user that the destination already exists.

Comment: @SuleymanSah : That could be possible if input request has other fields which has unique index, that case you can read the message for dup key name & match against it only after code does match to 11000(for not all other errors), it would be one more level of check only on negative scenarios that too only when inputting fields which have multiple uniques !!

Comment: And that will make your answer even more complex.

Comment: @SuleymanSah : I don’t think, I would not worry about writing code on negative scenarios that would execute once in a while ratherthan doing checks for each request - which is not needed if you know your request nd response :-) !!! Let’s say even if you do pre checks then you’ve to write ‘if’ blocks to check on all fields but if you do same check in error case you might just pass error message as is with one check...though it works, I wanted to know which scenarios does it make complex ?